# Adding data to particular data point on plot using mouse click

Tags: python, mouseevent, mayavi

I have developed subplots in mayavi and I want to add data on a particular point on that graph after clicking on that point. I have used mayavi.mlab.text3d but the text is not present on the data point. How to fix this